# TcpListener and TcpClient not found

Tags: c#, .net, windows, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm creating an w10 app, and want to add some networking. TcpListener and TcpClient classes cause *CS0246* (The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found).  System.Net.Sockets included.

How can i resolve the issue? Should I use something different to tcpClient for w10 apps?

- Visual Studio 2015 update 3
- .NET version 4.6

[code](http://meson.ad-l.ink/8bLrHBfLC/image.png)

Comment: Are we allowed to see the code?

Comment: What does VS say when your mouse is on `TcpClient` class?

Comment: @L.B  here's a snapshot: http://meson.ad-l.ink/68wYhVCJM/image.png - it's cyrillic, but actually says CS0246 error text.

Comment: [here's the code](http://meson.ad-l.ink/8bLrHBfLC/image.png) I tried the same thing in console app and no problem occurred. Seems strange for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the reference in the reference manager as well as in code:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
```

[How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Reference Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx)

Comment: `Are you sure.....` it is a question, not an answer. If you want to ask something, use *comments*

Comment: C'mon... I'm providing an answer to a very vague question. It's a matter of formatting lol... I'll edit

Comment: [that's all i found](http://polariton.ad-l.ink/85X7LZgvB/image.png) in reference manager

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you this site: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket

This is a good example which demonstrates the use of a stream socket (TCP) to send and receive data in Windows 10 Universal App.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it